# How do I import routes from other xml files in apache camel 3.0

Tags: apache-camel-3

I want to import routes from another xml file in apache camel 3.0. I tried to use the  and  as I found in the camel docs. But these tags are deprecated in camel 3.0. So it's not working for me. Please guide me with respect to camel 3.0

myRoute.xml

```
<routeContext id="myRoute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<restConfiguration bindingMode="auto" />

<rest path="/demo">
<post path="/route/getRoute" type="com.testing.demo.Employee" />
<to uri="direct:hello" />
</rest>

<route id="route1">
<from uri="direct:hello" />
<process ref="demoProcessor"/>
<to uri="log:info" />
</route>
</routeContext>
```

``
mainRoute.xml

```
<import resource="myRoute.xml"/>
 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <routeContextRef ref="myRoute"/>
</camelContext>
```